# How to add background color to particular row using pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination

[image]

Here i am iterating through array  using pagination.The array has the count variable in it which can be accessed by `{{x.count}}`.I need to add background color to the row with count=0 .

As shown in the image...I am need to show different color to the row with count=0

Comment: I need the background color for entire row,not the particular td

Comment: what will happen if the array.count is 0 for the all row?

Comment: Actually if the count=0 implies that i haven't visited that row,So i need to add some background color to the row with count=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css in combination with a class expression:

```
<tr dir-paginate="x in array" class="count-{{ x.count }}">
    <td scope="row">{{x.emailTo}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{x.subject}}</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
tr.count-0 td {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ddz1annb/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it, you might find is more 'angular':

```
<tr dir-paginate="x in array"
  ng-class-odd="'some-odd-class'"
  ng-class-even="'some-even-class'">
</tr>
```

The [ng-class-odd/ng-class-even](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven) only work with ng-repeat, so I assume (hope) your dir-paginate directive has an ng-repeat in it somewhere.